# Detaching all instances of a sprite AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

I'm building a tank game using AndEngine that has multiple levels, but I'm not using multiple scenes, I'm sticking to 1 Main Game Scene that should reset and modify itself when the user beats the level.

I'm able to successfully modify the scene, but I'm having an issue with removing the enemies. There are multiple instances of an enemy sprite that the user has to kill, but when the user successfully completes the requirement to advance a level(killing x number of enemies), the enemies aren't reset; the instances from the previous level haven't been removed from the screen.

As a result, when a user is on Level 2, there might still be 3 or 4 enemies roaming around from Level 1 that the user didn't need to kill.

I tried using detachChild to remove the enemy from the screen and attachChild to instantly add them back, but when the next level started, the enemies wouldn't spawn.

How can I remove all instances of the enemy sprite that are currently on the screen without affecting the spawning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are starting the game you have to create different layers(Entities) like gameLayer, 
background Layer, HUD Layer... .So that you can update the items based on the situation. 
This process make you unload resources  smoothly when level is completed.

Coming to your requirement ...  add every sprite instance to array list when it is created.
Remove all these as follows

```
 public static void removeSprites(List<Sprite> spriteList, IEntity scene){
        for(int i = spriteList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            final Sprite sprite = spriteList.get(i);
            scene.detachChild(sprite);
            spriteList.remove(i);
        }
        spriteList = null;
        System.gc();
    }
```

you must also unload Texture Atlases  in your game

Answer (score -1):

Well, try to use this method: `sprite.detachchildren()`